# Installshield 2012 Spring chokes when including DLL that has Powershell cmdlet inside (.Net)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powershell, installshield-2012

I'm using InstallShield 2012 Spring with Visual Studio 2010. (Requirement for the project I'm working on). The installer compiles and works fine with regular DLLs and EXEs that my project generates. However, there was a recent addition of a PowerShell cmdlet. The cmdlet is built inside a C# class library and output as a DLL. If I include that DLL in the file list, the InstallShield build chokes with the following errors:

Error   17  -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'MDAC27ENU.C9C35FC7_5AEE_4C1E_8BD2_80ED9FA87FFF:1033' for Feature 'Setup1_Files'.   ISDEV : error : -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'MDAC27ENU.C9C35FC7_5AEE_4C1E_8BD2_80ED9FA87FFF:1033' for Feature 'Setup1_Files'.

Error   18  -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLBASE.2D02443E_7002_4C0B_ABC9_EAB2C064397B:0' for Feature 'Setup1_Files'.    ISDEV : error : -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLBASE.2D02443E_7002_4C0B_ABC9_EAB2C064397B:0' for Feature 'Setup1_Files'.

Error   19  -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLSVR.CC1A8C58_27D1_4D38_BF1B_C0A5CBB90616:0' for Feature 'Installer_Files'.  ISDEV : error : -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLSVR.CC1A8C58_27D1_4D38_BF1B_C0A5CBB90616:0' for Feature 'Installer_Files'.

Error   20  -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLSVR1033.88C26F26_166C_4CD7_8175_38297C2276D7:0' for Feature 'Installer_Files'.  ISDEV : error : -4075: File not found. An error occurred merging Module 'SQLSVR1033.88C26F26_166C_4CD7_8175_38297C2276D7:0' for Feature 'Installer_Files'.

I'm not using any custom merge modules, and I've not been able to find much info on these module names using Google. What's more, if I create a brand new InstallShield project in Visual Studio and add that cmdlet DLL to the files list, I get the same errors. Adding Powershell as a prerequisite on the Installation Requirements tab of the Installsheid project (inside Visual Studio) has no effect.

Any ideas?

Charles.

Comment: Note, those should all say "Installer_Files". Setup1 is the name of the test project I created to see if the problem happened with a basic installer project. "Installer" is the name of the actual installer project.

Comment: What's the DLL's component's setting for .NET Scan at Build?